# How to route to a component programatically

Tags: react-native

I am trying to push a component when initial component is about to render. I am using the `react-native-router-flux` module. Unfortunately the `Action.checkpass` call does not execute while the one in `Button` tag does (i.e on click).
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
class Launch extends React.Component {

render(){
//transfer to checkpass
    Actions.checkpass;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Launch page</Text>
            <Button onPress={Actions.checkpass}>Go to Register page</Button>
        </View>
    );
}  
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Actions.route('checkpass');`